# Awkで、指定した行の引き算をしたい

Tags: awk

awkで、以下の方法で、指定した範囲の行を足すことができました。

```
awk 'NR==3,NR==8{m+=$1}END{print m}' test.txt
```

今度は、8行目の数字から、3行目の数字を引き算
した値を出したいです。どう書き直したらよいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 別方法として `awk -F'\n' -vRS= '{print $8 - $3}' test.txt` など。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば

```
awk 'NR==3{m3=$1}NR==8{m8=$1}END{print m8-m3}' test.txt
```

より短く

```
awk 'NR==3{m=$1}NR==8{print $1-m}' test.txt
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。長いバージョンの方で上手くいきました。